# asp.net get previous page from my site only

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, referrer

I'm currently using

```
Page.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
```

Which I have come to find out isn't going to always work since it comes from the browser.  In that case what is the safest way to get the previous page and check if it is part of my website or not?

My site has pages where users can download some zip files.  When they click on the zip file links a validation check is made so I need to know from which page they were on so I can return them back there after the validation is checked.   They can type in the url and try and download the file that way which would return a null for referrer.

Comment: don't return them anywhere or return to some default page if referrer cannot be obtained

Comment: I will try sending them to a page level above the pages that have the zip files if there is no referrer.  Is there security concerns for the referrer?

Comment: The *server* has absolutely *no* idea what the *browser's* previous page was. Referer is *not* the previous page, it's the page that contained the `<a>` link. Either ignore empty `UrlReferrer` parameters, or change your links or script to include a `returnto` parameter

Comment: Another alternative would be to store in the user's session information regarding the last page they loaded, but that's probably more likely to be confusing than useful.

Comment: Thank you.  I have added a query string if they are on one of my pages.  This way I can check for the query sting and if it is there I know they came from one of my pages.  If not I can redirect to a top level page.  Thanks